# Mysql ORDER BY with compound PK

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, query-optimization

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE price(
  product_id int,
  category_id int,
  epoch_id int,
  name varchar, 
  price decimal(10),
  add constraint primary key (product_id, category_id, epoch_id)
);
```

I want to select all prices for products in category, but all epochs:

```
SELECT * FROM prices where category_id = 1 ORDER BY product_id, category_id, epoch_id;
```

But I am afraid, that `ORDER BY` will be unable to use primary key and will take too much resources to sort the rows (as I specify `category_id = 1`, which is on the second place in the index)

I don't want to change column order in the index or create a new one. I want to understand, whether MySQL will be able to use clustered index to quickly perform ordering.

**UPDATE:**
I have generated about 100,000 rows and this is what I have:

```
explain SELECT * FROM price where category_id = 1 ORDER BY category_id, product_id, epoch_id;

id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  price       index       PRIMARY 12      97739   10  Using where

explain SELECT * FROM price where category_id = 1 ORDER BY category_id, epoch_id;
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  price       ALL                 97739   10  Using where; Using filesort


explain SELECT * FROM price where category_id = 1 ORDER BY category_id, epoch_id, product_id;
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  price       ALL                 97739   10  Using where; Using filesort

explain SELECT * FROM price where category_id = 1 ORDER BY product_id, epoch_id, category_id;
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  price       index       PRIMARY 12      97739   10  Using where

explain SELECT * FROM price where category_id = 1 ORDER BY product_id, epoch_id;
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  price       index       PRIMARY 12      97739   10  Using where
```

So now I have a few questions:

1. Why `product_id, epoch_id, category_id` does not use filesort, though order contradicts PK order? - Is it because `category_id` is rstricted by `WHERE` clause, and `product, epoch` order is preserved from PK?
2. Why `product_id, epoch_id` does not require filesort, but `category_id, epoch_id` does? - Actually the same reason, that `product_id, epoch_id` is preserved from PK
3. Actually `category_id` does matter at all and we can eliminate it from `ORDER BY`.

So, does it mean that MySQL will traverse clustered index and retrieve all the rows sorted by defaul, and won't need to re-order it then?

Comment: based on your primary key index  the where clause based on category id can't use the index .. .. if you have really performance  problem for this you must  think to add a new index

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN ...` and post the results here.. They will clearly explain you what will happen when you run the query.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, I don't currently have enough data (just a few rows), so execution plan will not be too much realistic. I am more interested in a theoretical possibility of this. 
I mean when we have found all ROWIDs, are we going to read it randomly or we can read it sorted straight away, as it is ordered fully by PK fields (and all these primary fields are selected in the query).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your Questions**

I see confusion in the `EXPLAINs`.  Some say "ALL"; some say "index..PRIMARY".  Well, for InnoDB, those are effectively the same.  The `PRIMARY KEY` is clustered with the data, in the same B+Tree.

(`EXPLAIN` was written back in the days before InnoDB, primarily for MyISAM, which did not cluster the PK.)

`EXPLAIN` is not detailed enough to give a clear answer to your question.  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` is better, but probably still not clear enough.

As for why "filesort" is missing...  Think about it.  If `category` is constant, then you effectively want things sorted by `(product_id, epoch_id)`.  And that is the order that that subset of the table is sorted by.  If you had tried any other combinations (eg, with `epoch_id` first), it would have needed to sort.  Your 2nd and 3rd cases do that (after ignoring the constant `category_id`).

For Q3:  Yes, it is equivalent to ORDER BY product_id, <strike>category_id,</strike> epoch_id.

"So, does it mean that MySQL will traverse clustered index and retrieve all the rows sorted by defaul, and won't need to re-order it then?"  -- Yes.  And "filesort" is an accurate (but incomplete) indication of such.

There are cases of `GROUP BY x ORDER BY b` where 2 sorts are needed, but `EXPLAIN` shows it only once.  (`EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` does provide detail.)

**Let me discuss this query:**

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  prices
    where  category_id = 1
    ORDER BY  product_id, category_id, epoch_id;
```

The Optimizer has two ways to approach it.

- Focus on filtering (`where  category_id = 1`) in hopes that there are not very many rows matching that restriction.
- Focus on the `ORDER BY`, hoping that the savings in avoiding the sort saves more than the cost of going through the entire table to do the filtering.

When given two situations like this, it gathers some statistics (which could be less than perfect) to make an educated guess of which way to perform the query.  Perhaps the main statistic (in your example) is what percentage of the table has `category=1`.

Let's say only a small number of rows have `category=1`.  Then this is optimal:

```
PRIMARY KEY(category_id, product_id, epoch_id)
```

In this case, the 'clustered' nature of the PK will let the query be performed by locating and reading only the rows `category=1` (plus one extra row to know it has stopped).  The B+Tree is efficient for both locating the first such row, and for scanning through all such rows.

Alternatively, let's say the PK cannot be changed.  Then a secondary `INDEX(category_id)` could be used.  This scans through the B+Tree for that index and jumps (one by one) over to the data to find the rows.

With either indexing, this case will end with sorting the rows found.

Let's say only a large number of rows have `category=1`.  Then this is optimal:

```
PRIMARY KEY(product_id, category_id, epoch_id)
```

That way, it can avoid the sort (aka "filesort").  However it reads all the rows, skipping over any that do not have `category=1`.

If you can't change the PK, then a secondary `INDEX(product_id, category_id, epoch_id)` would be somewhat useful.  But the jumping back and forth between the secondary index and the data BTree would be rather costly.

Which is better?  Which will the Optimizer pick?  It is hard to tell.

Comment: `IN(1)` turns into `=1`, so that is not an issue.  But Raymond is correct that `IN` with multiple elements will _not_ avoid the sort.

Comment: accidentally remove mine comment but i said `IN(1, 2)` not `IN(1)`, i know that is converted into `=1` ... But `WHERE category_id IN(1, 2)
    ORDER BY  product_id, category_id, epoch_id`  now i rethink should be able to use a index only as `category_id` is sorted within the `product_id` -> `primary key (product_id, category_id, epoch_id)`

Comment: Probably `= constant` and `IS NULL` are the only things that can avoid the sort (in this context).